# create table that has a date item in sqlite3 database in python

Tags: date, python-3.x, sqlite, create-table

I'm making a database for a website and it needs to take the users input of a date but I think I can do that bit. The part I'm struggling to do is create a table with the date item. What do I need to tell it to do when creating the table I've got`create table Results (GameID integer,Date ???????, primary key(GameID)`
I just need to to know what I set date to as its not an integer real or text.

I'm using python 3.2

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have a built-in date type.

SQLite can store dates [as a string or a number](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).